# Radiobox OnChange Event On JQuery lost CSS Styling

Tags: jquery, css, html, onchange

i want to ask a question regarding to onChange Radiobox event, the condition if I click on Domestic, it will span new radiobox, but my problem here, I lost JQuery Styling. Anyone knows how to solve it, your help is really appreciating. Thanks. Below I attach jsfield link for your view.

http://jsfiddle.net/dwgk3q0v/2/

```
 $(function () {
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function(e){

            if (( $(this).val() ) == "Domestic"){

   document.getElementById('ul-stageCus').innerHTML =('<fieldset id="foobar"> \
                                                     <label>Domestic \
                                                     <input name="foobar" type="radio" value="foo" /> \
                                                     </label> \
                                                     <label>Export \
                                                     <input name="foobar" type="radio" value="bar" /> \
                                                     </label> \
                                                     </fieldset>');
                           $('#ul-stageCus').append('<b>If Domestic, Please Select One :</b>');
                           $('#ul-stageCus').append('<fieldset id="foobar"> \
                                                     <label>Domestic \
                                                     <input name="foobar" type="radio" value="foo" /> \
                                                     </label> \
                                                     <label>Export \
                                                     <input name="foobar" type="radio" value="bar" /> \
                                                     </label> \
                                                     </fieldset>');                   
            }

          })
       })
    `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `.enhanceWithin()` method.

```
$("#ul-stageCus").enhanceWithin();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwgk3q0v/8/

Comment: Great I could help you :)